# WPF ComboBox SelectedItem property is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this combo box:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="Mod.Code" Header="Mod" Width="100*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource modViewSource}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Mod}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is the data source:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="modViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type AutoPBW:Mod}, CreateList=True}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Code"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

And here is the model property:

```
/// <summary>
/// The mod used for this game.
/// </summary>
public Mod Mod { get; set; }
```

My problem is that the `SelectedItem` binding is not working - I always get the first item in the list, instead of the `Mod` object that belongs to the game data bound to the item in the `DataGrid`. How can I display the correct `Mod`?

edit: here is Mod.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AutoPBW
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A game mod, or the stock game.
    /// </summary>
    public class Mod
    {
        public Mod(string code, string engineCode)
        {
            Code = code;
            Engine = Engine.Find(engineCode);
            IsUnknown = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A unique code name for this mod. Used in PBW URLs.
        /// </summary>
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Code;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The game engine that this mod uses.
        /// </summary>
        public Engine Engine { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The path to the mod's root directory, relative to the engine's root directory.
        /// </summary>
        public string Path { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The path to the mod's savegame directory, relative to the engine's root directory.
        /// </summary>
        public string SavePath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The path to the mod's empire setup directory, relative to the engine's root directory.
        /// </summary>
        public string EmpirePath { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is this an unknown mod?
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsUnknown { get; set; }

        public static Mod Find(string code, string defaultEngineCode = null)
        {
            if (code == null)
                return null;
            var old = Config.Instance.Mods.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);
            Mod nu;
            if (old == null || old.IsUnknown)
            {
                // load from default if present
                var d = Config.Default.Mods.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);
                if (d != null)
                    nu = d;
                else
                    nu = new Mod(code, defaultEngineCode); // let the user know what the code is so he can find the mod
            }
            else
                nu = old;
            if (nu != old)
            {
                if (old != null)
                    Config.Instance.Mods.Remove(old);
                Config.Instance.Mods.Add(nu);
            }
            return nu;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented INPC for `Mod` property?

Comment: Please add the whole implementation of ```Mod``` to your question.

Comment: No, I have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I will add Mod.cs to my question.

Comment: Do you intend to send the `Mod` property data to the `ComboBox`? If this is the case your binding source must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to update the binding. Otherwise the binding will behave like `BindingMode.OneTime`.

Comment: I don't care if it's only bound one time, I can update it myself if I need to. I personally think the mvvm "pattern" introduces code bloat. It's not binding at all which is my problem.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` has nothing to do with MVVM. It's part of the framework's binding mechanism. You didn't answer. It's not clear what is not working. Do you intend to send data to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`? If so how do you update it wiithout raising the `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: Oh, the combo box was just going to display the `Code` property of the mod, and let the user pick a mod to associate with a game. Not sure what you mean by "send data to the `ComboBox.SelectedItem`"...

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel to make sure `SelectedItem` **Mod** is updated in UI thread

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? In my opinion the mvvm "pattern" introduces nothing but code bloat because you have to duplicate your model classes at the view model level. I prefer to bind directly to models, using converters as necessary to massage the data.

Comment: @ekolis You can use [PropretyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to make implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` much easier. It will automatically raise PropertyChanged events for all your properties in all classes that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` without bloating your source code.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of that, but never was able to get it working when I tried it out. Not sure if I configured something wrong or what...